# WP Non-www to www rewrite/redirection on AWS ELB

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb, no-www

I was told by my IT department looking after AWS that it is not possible to redirect non-www to www domain name because of the AWS load balanced environment - and that it is not single IP

I am running a wordpress site and I have tried this in the lb .htaccess files with no luck.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Just wanting to know if there is another way or is it definitely not possible?
thanks

Comment: Where is the DNS hosted?  If Route 53 then it's quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DNS Hosted Zone Create one CNAME record with www which should point to your ELB domain .

Edit your .htaccess file with this configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear cache of your browser and try to access on www domain .